# Does $\frac{d}{dx} e^{nx}$ always equal $ne^{nx}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find the derivative of $e^{-16t}$ from $y = e^{-16t}\cos(9t)$.

I am having trouble because I'm not sure how to handle $e$ when it is to the power of a constant multiplied by a variable.

I have read [this web page](https://socratic.org/questions/derivative-of-e-2x). but I don't understand the notation.

I have plugged this into the derivative calculator in [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(e%5E%7B-16t%7D%5Cright)), but I'm not sure if the answer will be similar regardless what the constant is.

*Does $\frac{d}{dx} e^{nx}$* always equal $ne^{nx}$?

Comment: Have you learned the Chain Rule yet?

Comment: The result immediately follows from the chain rule. Yes if $n$ is constant because derivative of $nx$ is $n$.

Comment: @Bladewood Kind-of. I have a little bit of practice with $f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$ but nothing with the weird fraction one $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$.

Comment: It is the same thing. $f'(g(x))=\frac{df}{dg}$.

Comment: @user Sorry! I am horrible with math notation. I assume $\frac{df}{dg}$ is the same thing as $\frac{dy}{du}$?

Comment: In any case if  $f=y$ and $g=u$.

Comment: $u$ = $nx$ $\frac{dy}{du}$ = $e^u$ $\frac{du}{dx}$ = $n$ $\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $ne^u$ Or you can also say  $g(x) = nx$ $f'(g(x)) = e^{g(x)}$ $g'(x) = n$ and notice they are basically the same thing but different notation.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You have to make sure that you are including the negative sign in "n". Which means that $n=-16$.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the chain rule
$\frac{d}{dx}e^{y(x)}=\frac{d}{dy}e^{y(x)}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}y(x)$

Comment: Thanks! I assume I find $\frac{d}{dy}e^{y(x)}   \cdot    \frac{d}{dx}y(x)$ like any other derivative? IE, first find both  $\frac{d}{dy}e^{y(x)}$ and  $\frac{d}{dx}y(x)$, then I apply the product rule $\frac{[f'(x) \cdot g(x)] - [g'(x) \cdot f(x)]}{(g(x))^2}$?

Comment: You do not apply the product rule because you are not taking the derivative of a product of functions, but rather taking the product of derivatives of functions.

Comment: @MatthewLiu So, once I find the derivatives, I just multiply them out normally?

Comment: You use chain rule to find the derivate of your $e$ function then use the product rule to find the derivate of your entire function. The formula you have written above is not the product rule its the quotient rule.

Comment: @BorKari Whoops! thanks for the correction.

Comment: @LuminousNutria: it is not the derivative of a product of functions, it is the derivative of $f(g(x))$, with $f: x\to e^x$ and $g: x \to nx$

Comment: Oh, I see! thank you!